# How to call an event when clicking a Google Maps API marker (from array)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My map shows an array of markers (exactly like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex) but I want to add an event to each marker. So if I click marker 1, function1() shall load, marker 2 - function2() and so on. How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Use the array to store the function too(either a reference or a anonymous function):

```
function1 = function(){alert('Bondi Beach(function reference)')}

var beaches = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, function1],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5,function(){alert('Coogee Beach(anonymous function)')}]
  /*more items*/
];
```

applying the listener inside the loop:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var beach = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',beach[4])
  }
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**check the below code
this may help u**

```
addMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(PoiLat, PoiLon),
    html: 'any Information',
    map: map
});

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(addMarker, 'click', function(event) {

        infowindow.setContent("<div class=infoWndw style=height:160px;width:360px>" + this.html + "</div>");
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: this goes in the right direction but it's only for one marker, not for the array as shown in my example above

Comment: u can place multiple markers using the above code
**use loop**

Comment: or u can put ur all markers in an array
then u can access that array as per ur requirment